# Javascript form submit not working in Safari while other browser working fine

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, form-submit

I am working in Stripe payment gateway. After successful payment response I need to submit the form, page will redirect and order will create.
This works perfectly fine in Firefox, Chrome but not in Safari in few cases.

Here is my code

```
function handleServerResponse(response) {
  if (response.error) {
    // Show error from server on payment form
    if(response.payment_intent_id !== undefined){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "stripe_response_save.php",
        data: "id="+response.payment_intent_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(r){
            form3.submit();
        }
        });
    }
    alert(response.error);
    setLoading(false);
    
  } else if (response.requires_action) {
    // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
    stripe.handleCardAction(
      response.payment_intent_client_secret
    ).then(handleStripeJsResult);
  } else {
    // Show success message
    $("#pmtint_id").val(response.payment_intent_id);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "stripe_response_save.php",
    //data: result,
    data: "id="+response.payment_intent_id,
    cache: false
    }).done(function(r){
        alert("Payment done, now order will create");
        document.getElementsByName("stripe_form")[0].submit();
    })
    return false;
    
    
  }
}
```

On the very last block after successful payment under the ajax success response form submit not working in Safari. Still not able troubleshoot. Anyone can help me will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome working fine. The Macbook I have it's also working fine. But some customers facing the issue during order placing. And they all using Macbook. One of the customer informed us that he used Safari version 16.0 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614). May be something happening on that version

Comment: That's a pretty recent version, the latest version is 16.2, so probably not a version incompatibility. Without more details about the problem we're not likely to be able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Does `form3.submit()` work? Is `document.getElementsByName("stripe_form")[0]` the same as `form3`? If so, why not use `form3.submit()` at the end as well?

Comment: "something happened" and "not working" are not descriptive enough for us to help you.

Comment: @Barmar form3.submit() is a different form . And document.getElementsByName("stripe_form")[0] is different. I tried both and still the issue persist not all Safari version but few. As one of customer reported that he is using Safari 16. Not all the Safari version has this issue. Every 1 or 2 day we facing this that payment done but order not created as form not submitted

Comment: how do you expect anyone to debug this without any specific details? If I have to guess, I suspect it may be related to browser extensions they have enabled.